# Detailed documentation on the Hunspell. Very needed

Tags: hunspell

Who has detailed documentation on the Hunspell format?

Unfortunately, I found out that it is difficult to find detailed documentation for this format. This is all the more strange because Hunspell is considered to be a very popular format.

**Maybe someone else has utilities to work with Hunspell?**

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/hunspell.5.html

Comment: *Are you looking for something like this*
Thank you!